# Upper and lower sums of trigonometric functions

Tags: real-analysis, calculus

Let $ f : [0, π/2] → \mathbb{R} $ be a function $x \rightarrow \sin(x)$

Determine the upper and lower sums $\overline{S_p}(f)$ and $\underline{S_p}(f)$, when the partition is $ P = (0, π/4, π/2).$

How would we approach this with trigonometric functions?

Comment: What do yo call the sums, and how is the parition used ?

Comment: Could you elaborate a bit? The upper and lower sum are denoted as $\overline{S_p}(f)$ and $\underline{S_p}(f)$ respectively.

Comment: Are you in the context of Riemannian integration/Darboux sums ? Don't assume we know what you are learning.

Comment: Ah, sorry about not letting you know the context. Yes, indeed Riemann integration.

Comment: Just find the global minima and maxima in the intervals.